# Differential equation $x\dfrac{dy}{dx}-xy=y^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I rearrange this ODE so that I can use the basic ODE techniques to solve it i.e. separable, first order using integrating factor and/or Exact ODE.

$x\dfrac{dy}{dx}-xy=y^2$

Comment: It is a Bernoulli type equation. Introduce a new variable $z=y^{-1}$ and divide your equation by $y^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

In the same spirit as Raskolnikov's comment, define $$y=\frac{e^x}{z}$$ and you will end with $$z'=-\frac{e^x}{x}$$ from which $$z=-\text{Ei}(x)+C$$ where $\text{Ei}(x)$ is the exponential integral.

**Added after the typo was discovered.**

Let $y_n$ be the solution of the differential equation $$x^n\dfrac{dy}{dx}-xy=y^2$$ and see the impact of a typo on the value of the exponent $n$.

We have $$y_0=\frac{2 e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}}{C-\sqrt{2 \pi }
   \text{erfi}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}$$ $$y_1=\frac{e^x}{C-\text{Ei}(x)}$$ $$y_2=\frac{x}{C-\log (x)}$$ $$y_3=\frac{x}{C e^{\frac{1}{x}} x-x-1}$$ $$y_4=\frac{2 x}{ C e^{\frac{1}{2 x^2}} x+\sqrt{2 \pi } e^{\frac{1}{2 x^2}} x
   \text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} x}\right)-2}$$ and so on !

Comment: $y\equiv0$ is also a solution.

Comment: Is it ? Joke but thanks to point it. I have the bad tendency of forgetting obvious and trivial solutions. Cheers :-)

Comment: I can get up to your second last line and can't evaluate the integral from there on probably because I don't know what Ei(x) is. Can you explain or are there alternative methods because my solution guide says $y=\frac{-x}{ln|x|+c}$

Comment: Either you have a typo in the equation given in the post or the book is wrong. I confirm that for $xy'-xy=y^2$, the solution is $$y=\frac{e^x}{C-\text{Ei}(x)}$$ in which $Ei$ is the exponential integral (you did learn it yet). I must confess that I was surprised they gave you such a differential equation. Cheers :-)

Comment: You legend, thanks to your comment I realised I have a typo i.e. instead of whats above, it should read $x^2\dfrac{dy}{dx}-xy=y^2$. It now makes a lot more sense to me.

Comment: $x^2 y'-xy=y^2$ would give you the answer of your solution guide !!

Comment: So, define $y=\frac{x}{z}$ and you will admire the beauty of your new differential equation in $z$. Cheers

Comment: I just completed it the normal way. But then did it your way (a one liner for an ODE is the first time that has ever happened to me) and indeed it just confirmed what I already knew about you i.e. "You are a legend."

Comment: I suppose that you are just kidding me ! I am an alien but don't repeat it to anyone, since I am undercover. Cheers and thanks :-)

Comment: coffee sometime???

Comment: Quite often. I have so much fun and pleasure working mathematics that I shall not stop enjoying !